# direct images and open immersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme (possibly regular), with $\dim(X)\geq 2$, and $U_1$, $U_2$ open affine subschemes of $X$ such that $X\backslash(U_1\cup U_2)$ is a single point $x$. Let $j:U_1\cup U_2\to X$ be the inclusion.

What are the sheaves $\cal E$ on $X$ which are direct images $j_*L$, where $L$ is a vector bundle on $U_1\cup U_2$, trivial on $U_1$ and $U_2$ ?

Comment: They will certainly be reflexive sheaves, at least when $X$ is (S2) (e.g. regular); see \[Tag [0EBJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EBJ)\]. But maybe you were hoping for some more explicit description? (It bears some similarity to clutching functions in topology, but I'm not aware of any algebraic version thereof.)

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn  Thank you for this reference. Since the only rank one reflexive sheaves on a regular scheme are the line bundles, in the regular case j_*L is the unique extension of L to a line bundle on X. I was also interested in the case of a non reduced X such that the underlying reduced scheme is regular. But this seems much more complicated.